# Entity Framework: добавление объектов в БД с Navigation Property

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, entity

Имеется две таблицы БД:

[image: БД]

Между ними одна связь: `BadObjectID` является внешним ключом для одного из столбцов таблицы `BadParameters`.

Соответственно Entity Framework сделал два типа Entity: `BadObject` и `BadParameter`.
Я хочу добавить в БД новую запись `BadObject` и сразу список `BadParameter` для него.

Для этого я создаю `BadObject`, и добавляю в его NavigationProperty `BadParameters` список Entity типа `BadParameter`. Т.е. я хочу записать данные в две таблицы.

```
   var badObj = new BadObject
                {
                    SourceID = _source.SourceID,
                    URL = o.URL,
                    Date = DateTime.Now,
                    RankID = (byte) o.Rank
                };
                // Adding Navigation Property
                badObj.BadParameters = new List<BadParameter>();
                foreach (var bp in o.Parameters.Select(p => new BadParameter
                {
                    ParameterID = Repository.Parameters.First(x => x.ParameterName == p.Key).ParameterID,
                    Value = "value",
                    ErrorDescription = "error",
                    Confirmed = false,
                    Validated = true
                }))
                {
                    badObj.BadParameters.Add(bp);
                }
   return badObj;
```

Пытаюсь сохранить изменения и получаю фриз на методе `db.SaveChanges();`:

```
// ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
// LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
using (var db = new RPDMEntitiesCustomized())
{
   db.BadObjects.AddRange(badObjectsList);
   db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Если не добавлять Navigation Property `BadParameters`, тогда в таблицу `BadObjects` все нормально записывается. В чем может быть проблема? Вообще, я не знаю правильно ли я это делаю. Ексепшн почему-то не вылетает.

Comment: Судя по коду, правильно. По крайней мере, по тому коду, который приведён. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko, спасибо за ссылку. Там суть та же. Буду смотреть что у меня не так. Не пойму почему не выбрасывает исключение..

Answer (score 1):

Не по теме, но все же: ваш код можно написать проще.

```
return new BadObject
       {
            SourceID = _source.SourceID,
            URL = o.URL,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            RankID = (byte) o.Rank,

            BadParameters = o.Parameters.Select(p => new BadParameter
            {
                ParameterID = Repository.Parameters.First(x => x.ParameterName == p.Key).ParameterID,
                Value = "value",
                ErrorDescription = "error",
                Confirmed = false,
                Validated = true
            }).ToList(),
      };
```